# ubuntu 20.04 does not start up properly in virtual box

Tags: 20.04, virtualbox, windows-10

Virtual Box is the latest version. I have windows 10. I setup ubuntu 64-bit and make everything as recommended, RAM, memory allocation. When I install ubuntu, the screen shows up, but no application. The mouse cursor is a rotating circle, like loading. I cannot open terminal. I waited and waited till now. 
When I add VBoxGuestAddition.iso, it cannot install in ubuntu. Is that relevant? I don't know. 
When I install ubuntu disk image, it does not show try ubuntu or install ubuntu, choose language, country, etc. It just directly goes to ubuntu screen.

Comment: You've not said if you're talking about Ubuntu Server, Ubuntu Desktop ... as the requirements differ for each, so did you provide the requirements for which you're trying to use? and which is it?   Did you verify your ISO of *unstated* 20.04?  https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0

Comment: @guiverc I downloaded from ubuntu.com. It is ubuntu 20.04 Lts version. What do you think my problem is?

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Desktop?  Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Server?  etc...  (desktop has far *higher* requirements than server) from your description it sounds like a setup problem on your host OS (windows-10) but you're lacking specific details for anything else...

Comment: @guiverc it was Desktop version. How do I find more detail if the screen does not show up? Cannot run terminal.

Comment: I would start with the basics - did you verify the ISO as being valid (my first comment, you're wasting your time doing anything else if that ISO has even 1 bit corrupted..)  Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Desktop tries to verify itself, however it `virtualbox` isn't given enough resources, it will misbehave & fail to validate which Oracle say is a end-user error/problem; sufficient resources need to be provided; why the requirements are available - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was facing this issue just now - the solution was to simply right-click the virtual machine and choose "Reset". please refer to the image attached.

@guiverc if you happen to check the image, I've highlighted something of a reminder for you too. @white dark was probably new to this, which is why they didn't go into the finer details - but needed help nonetheless.

[Solution screenshot showing where to right-click and how to restart.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bedtf.png)